# libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file

Tags: apache-http-server, centos-6

I tried installing my application in a CentOS 6 server. But while I am starting Apache(`Server version: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix)`), I am getting error like

> [error] install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '.../mysql/mysql.so'
>   for module DBD::mysql: libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory at *
>
> # ldd  mysql.so
>
> ```
>     linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb8518000)
>     libmysqlclient.so.15 => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.15 (0x00007fc047163000)
>     libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fc046f45000)
>     libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fc046d0e000)
>     libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fc046af5000)
>     libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc046870000)
>     libssl.so.6 => not found
>     libcrypto.so.6 => not found
>     libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc0464dc000)
>     libfreebl3.so => /usr/lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007fc04627a000)
>     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003f8a600000)
>     libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc046076000)
> ```

I have installed openssl and openssl-devel also.

Please help

Comment: Install **mysql-devel** also.

Answer (score 0):

Having the file name, you can find package that contains that file using [RPM Search](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/2/simple/2) or `yum whatprovides` command.

Files `libcrypto.so.6` and `libcrypto.so.6` are contained in `openssl098e` package.